# Backing up a Azure virtual machine (V2) in Portal through Resource Group

Tags: azure, backup, portal, resourcemanager

Backup of virtual Machine in the Azure new portal.
Backup of Azure V2 VMs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its available now (PREVIEW mode).

Its possible to backup the Azure V2 VM's ie Backup VM in new Azure Resource Manager portal

Check this link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/